# error when creating a profile image with canvas discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm having this error when I run the command that generates an image with profile information
I am trying to make a profile command that will sample an image with profile information of the member who used the command but is giving this error in the terminal, I have been trying for a while.

I would like help to solve this problem, I do not like coming to ask for help but I have been breaking my head for hours and I cannot find a solution to solve this problem

error

```
(node:33728) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: (intermediate value).setColor(...).addImage is not a function
    at createCanvas (C:\Users\Akure\Desktop\erzavdois\src\commands\Perfil\s.js:29:14)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Object.module.exports.run (C:\Users\Akure\Desktop\erzavdois\src\commands\Perfil\s.js:90:46)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:33728) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:33728) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

code

```
const { Canvas } = require('canvas-constructor');
const { createCanvas, loadImage } = require('canvas');
const { MessageAttachment } = require('discord.js');
const { get } = require('node-superfetch');
const db = require('../../../database')
module.exports.run = async (client,message,args) => {

    let user = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || message.guild.members.cache.find(r => r.user.username.toLowerCase() === args.join(' ').toLocaleLowerCase()) || message.guild.members.cache.find(r => r.displayName.toLowerCase() === args.join(' ').toLocaleLowerCase()) || message.member;
    if (user.user.bot) return message.channel.send(`**Bots Don't Have A Profile!**`);

    let bg = await db.fetch(`bg_${user.id}`)
    if (bg === null) bg = 'https://i.imgur.com/cnCS5SG.jpg'

    let bg2 = await db.fetch(`bg2_${user.id}`)
    if (bg2 === null) bg2 = 'https://i.imgur.com/O8rg78M.png'
    
    let background = bg;
    let background3 = bg2;

    async function createCanvas() {
        var username = user.user.username;
        var name = username.length > 10 ? username.substring(0, 12) + "..." : username;
        var { body: avatar } = await get(user.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'jpg', size: 1024 }));
        var { body: background1 } = await get(background)
        var { body: background2 } = await get(background3);

        return new Canvas(600, 500)
            .setColor('#000000')
            .addImage(background1, 0, 0, 600, 500)
            .addBeveledImage(background2, 0, 0, 600, 400)
            .setTextFont('30px Impact')
            .addText(`${name}'s Profile Card`, 190, 105)
            .addText('Fishes', 445, 140)
            .addText('-', 530, 140)
            .addText(`${crFormat(fish)}`, 550, 140)
            .setTextFont('20px Impact')
            .addText('Tags', 525, 190)
            .addText(workTag, 507, 230)
            .addText(begTag, 520, 270)
            .addText(gamesTag, 520, 310)
            .setTextFont('30px Impact')
            .addText('_______', 505, 190)
            .addText('_______', 505, 230)
            .addText('_______', 505, 270)
            .addText('_______', 505, 310)
            .addText('_____________________', 150, 396)
            .addText('_____________________', 152, 423)
            .addText('|', 148, 422)
            .addText('|', 503, 422)
            .setTextFont('28px Courier New')
            .addText(`About ${user.user.username}`, 160, 182)
            .setTextFont('30px Impact')
            .addText('Level', 190, 140)
            .addText('Ranks', 310, 140)
            .setTextFont('23px Impact')
            .addText('Works', 31, 260)
            .addText('Begs', 31, 315)
            .addText('Games', 31, 370)
            .addText('-', 97, 260)
            .addText('-', 85, 315)
            .addText('-', 100, 370)
            .addText(`${crFormat(work)}`, 31, 285)
            .addText(`${crFormat(begs)}`, 31, 340)
            .addText(`${crFormat(games)}`, 31, 395)
            .setTextFont('30px Impact')
            .addText('Total XP', 160, 340)
            .addText('Balance', 160, 380)
            .addText(`${crFormat(xp)}`, 273, 340)
            .addText(`$${crFormat(balance)}`, 278, 380)
            .setTextAlign('center')
            .setTextFont('20px Courier New')
            .setTextFont('30px Impact')
            .addText(`${level}`, 280, 140)
            .addText(`${vip}`, 410, 140)
            .addText('-', 260, 140)
            .addText('-', 393, 140)
            .addText('-', 263, 340)
            .addText('-', 268, 380)
            .setColor("#459466")
            .addRect(154, 400, difference, 25)
            .setTextFont("18px RobotoRegular")
            .setColor("#000000")
            .setTextAlign('left')
            .addText(`${Info}`, 165, 200)
            .addText(`XP: ${xp} / ${nxtLvlXp}`, 300, 418)
            .addCircularImage(avatar, 90, 93, 89, 104)
            .toBufferAsync();
    }

    const attachment = new MessageAttachment(await createCanvas(), 'profile.png')
    message.channel.send(attachment)

}


module.exports.help = {
  name: "s",
  aliases: [],
  status: 'on',
  category: 'perfil'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, `.setColor(...).addImage is not a function`.
You need to define a variable and then set the color, add an image, etc.

```js
let canvas = new Canvas(600, 500);

canvas.setColor('#000000');
canvas.addImage(background1, 0, 0, 600, 500);
canvas.addBeveledImage(background2, 0, ;0, 600, 400);
canvas.setTextFont('30px Impact')
canvas.addText(`${name}'s Profile Card`, 190, 105);
/*
 * And so on...
 *
 */
```

and then `return canvas;`.

Comment: `Canvas.setColor is not a function` `let canvas = new Canvas(600, 500);
               Canvas.setColor('#000000')
               Canvas.addImage(background1, 0, 0, 1920, 1080)
               Canvas.addBeveledImage(background2, 0, 0, 1920, 1080)
               Canvas.setTextFont('72px Impact')
               Canvas.addText(`${name}`, 1160, 300)
               Canvas.setTextFont('72px Impact')
               Canvas.setTextFont('30px Impact')
               Canvas.setTextFont('20px Impact')`

Comment: `Canvas` is the object you can initialize. I initialized it and named the variable `canvas` with a lowercase "c". `Canvas.setColor` is not a function but `canvas.setColor` is.

Comment: when I put `canvas` on all of them, it returns the error `ReferenceError: get is not defined` these errors are from the avatar and background, it is in the code up there.